# Windows 10: Imposible desvincular cuenta corporativa - borrar del registro

Tags: windows, directorioactivo, windows10, registro-windows

Estoy utilizando Windows 10, más exactamente la última versión insider for business.

En la configuración de mi cuenta tenía asociada mi cuenta corporativa así:

[image: Work account]

Y todo iba de maravilla hasta que al tratar de conectarme a la VPN me comenzaron a salir unos errores de certificados, así que fuí hasta allí a darle **Sync** pero nunca funcionó.

Debido a esto supuse que lo mejor era desvincular la cuenta y volverla a vincular, así que lo hice tal como se ve en la imagen siguiente, donde claramente ya no está.

[image: Cuenta corporativa desvinculada]

Luego fui a revisar en Work Access donde se supone que ya no debería haber nada, pero el perfil sigue apareciendo y aunque le de **remover** siempre me pide que lo borre de la cuenta, paso que desde luego ya he seguido.

[image: Imposible borrar perfil laboral]

Así que trato entonces de unir nuevamente la cuenta laboral, **dado que ya no existe**, pero al hacerlo el sistema me está diciendo que **SI existe** y que en efecto la cuenta ya se encuentra asociada.

[image: El dispositivo ya está matriculado]

He tratado de borrarlo buscando llaves de registro y comandos de powershell sin éxito, estoy muy convencido de que por powershell debe ser posible de solucionar, sin embargo no he podido dar con el chiste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten presente que no es lo mismo tener vinculada la cuenta a *Azure AD*, que a la administración MDM desde *Work access*. Aunque las dos pueden trabajar con una sola cuenta, pueden ser excluyentes.

Lo extraño es que en **Acerca de** debería aparecerte algo como **«Desconectarse de la organización»**; ¿Tú te uniste manualmente, o fue a través de alguna directiva de la empresa?

En cuando al *enrollment*, se supone que la información debería alojarse en una subclave debajo de **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments**

En mi caso está en esta:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments\126984D1-2765-46B7-BC31-B85A342070F2

Prueba eliminado el valor que te corresponde y ver si la cuenta queda desvinculada.

Comment: Estas recomendaciones más parecen un comentario a la pregunta, que una respuesta a la misma. En StackOverflow, el espacio de la respuesta se utiliza cuando tienes información que responde (en este caso resuelve) la duda o problema planteado en la pregunta. En este caso, más parece que lo que se busca es pedir más información o aclaraciones al OP. Esa información adicional puede llevarnos a una respuesta, o no, por lo que te sugiero que utilices los comentarios y una vez estas seguro que tienes la respuesta, entonces ya la publiques como tal. Un saludo y bienvenido a SOes.

Comment: Muchas gracias. No estoy todavía acostumbrado a la dinámica de estos foros. Ya edité para agregar la sugerencia y ver si eso resuelve el problema.

Comment: al final lo resolvi de otra manera borrando el device desde el CompanyPortal, sin embargo replique el escenario y tal como lo planteas me funcionó y es mucho más cercano a la solución que buscaba.